# How to update URL from request response using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function that is attempting to closely emulate a form submit.

```
function fopen() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", open_url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
      create: 0,
      jobtype: jobtype,
      name: document.getElementById("file-selector").value
  }));
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        document.write(xhr.responseText);
    }
    else {
      console.log('ErR0r')
    }
  }
}
```

The behavior is close to identical, but the URL is not being updated after the response. I see there is an xhr.responseURL attribute but how can I actually get this to show in the address bar? And is there an exact full JavaScript implementation of form submit I can refer to in order to keep things as similar as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the page's URL, set `window.location.href`.